# googleCloudStorageDeleteOperator URL encode "/"

Tags: google-cloud-storage, airflow

I want to delete temporary file at the end of my DAG in a GCS bucket. When I add the list of values in the arguments object I get an error that the file is not found. The reason is the symbole / is URL encoded %2F.

```
gcs_delete_temp = GoogleCloudStorageDeleteOperator(
    task_id="gcs_delete_temp",
    bucket_name=f"super_bucket",
    objects=[
        "rte/temp/{{ macros.ds_add(ds, -10) }}_injectee.parquet",
        "rte/temp/{{ macros.ds_add(ds, -10) }}_soutiree.parquet"
    ]
)
```

I got the error:

> google.api_core.exceptions.NotFound: 404 DELETE https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/super_bucket/o/rte%2Ftemp%2F2020-07-25_injectee.parquet: Not Found

I tried to escape them but the ** symbole is URL encoded too.

Is that a bug ? Or a feature ?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to start off by trying to delete at least one temporary file from your GCS bucket, and then begin to add filters to objects array. As I believe this may be due to your implementation of the object list in your code. Seems like Apache Airflow provides a code snippet to delete objects from a GCS bucket, more information on this can be found [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_modules/airflow/contrib/operators/gcs_delete_operator.html).

I would also recommend you have a look at [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/managing-dags#deleting_a_dag) deleting a DAG file from the environment's dags folder in Cloud Storage.
This method however would require you to [script gcloud CLI commands](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/scripting-gcloud), which would be effective method in handling output and automating tasks as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think the behavior is correct for the encoding URI ( please check this page https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-endpoints#encoding )

For example, in order to delete parquet files in
`gs://my_bucket/example0/example1/part-*.parquet` 
this configuration works for me :

```
gcs_delete_temp = GoogleCloudStorageDeleteOperator(
    task_id="gcs_delete_temp",
    bucket_name="my_bucket",
    prefix= "example0/example1/part"
)
```